# `dplyr::filter` in `mapply`

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following code I am expecting the same result as for dplyr::filter( tab, A < 3 )

```
tab <- data.frame( A = 1:3, B = letters[1:3] )
mapply( dplyr::filter, .data = list(tab), list( quote(A < 3) ), SIMPLIFY = FALSE  )
```

However, an error is raised:

> Error: Evaluation error: could not find function "<".

On the other hand, this code works perfectly:

```
mapply( dplyr::filter, .data = list(tab), MoreArgs = list( quote(A < 3) ), SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
```

What is the source of the error?

Comment: In the second case you are specify the argument for `filter`.  Not clear why you need a `mapply` here instead of `filter(tab, A < 3)`.  Also, in tidyverse, it would be `map(list(tab), ~ .x %>% filter(!!quo(A < 3)))`

Comment: I think it would be because `mapply` considers the `...` as arguments to its function instead of argument of the `filter`.  Specifying `MoreArgs` is better when the `filter` expressions are passed into `...` You can explicitly use anonymous function call `mapply(function(x, y)  filter(x, !!y), list(tab), list(quote(A < 3)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: You seem right about `mapply` considering `...` as arguments to its function and not as those of `filter`. In the given case the suggested anonymous function works well, alternatively `filter_` solves the issue too. In general, `function(x, ...) do.call( fun, c(list(x), list(...)) ) ` should do it.